# http request completion handler and closure firing before completion of the response

Tags: json, swift, http, httprequest, completionhandler

So the issue I have currently is that the closure is firing before the completion of the request response.

I have implemented a completion handler and closure, I am unsure if I have done this incorrectly or if the method in which I am calling the functions is incorrect.

here is the request containing the completion handler.

```
func ElevationRequest(listOfPointsToQuery: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, success:Bool,completeHandler: (Bool) -> Void){
        var processedQueryPoints = Array<String>() //points which have been ordered based on the execution order are stored here
        var newStringCoordinate = String() // the next coordinates are stored here temporarily
        var finalStringConvertedCoordinates = String()
        var jsonResponse = String()
        for i in 0..<listOfPointsToQuery.count{ //go through all listed points to be queried within the http request sent to googles elevation api - returned as a json format dictionary
            var latHolder = String(listOfPointsToQuery[i].latitude)
            var lonHolder = String(listOfPointsToQuery[i].longitude)
            newStringCoordinate = latHolder + "," + lonHolder
            processedQueryPoints.append(newStringCoordinate)
                    }
        finalStringConvertedCoordinates = processedQueryPoints.joined(separator: "%7C") //google documentation demonstrates the use of the pipe ("|") - using pipe causes errors and the function will not.. function. "%7C" is used in its place
        let apiKey = "AIzaSyAPqcl47sO5eJIkdl46Ww-uJLgv_7aJq3I"
        print(finalStringConvertedCoordinates)
        struct ElevationResponse: Decodable {
            let results: [ElevationResult]
        }
        struct ElevationResult: Decodable {
             let elevation: Double
             let location: LatLngLiteral
             let resolution: Double?
            
        enum resultKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case results = "results"
            case elevation = "elevation"
            case location = "location"
            case resolution = "resolution"
            case lat = "lat"
            case lon = "lon"
            }
        }
        struct LatLngLiteral: Decodable {
             let lat: Double
             let lng: Double
        }
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?&locations=\(finalStringConvertedCoordinates)&key=\(apiKey)") else {
                    print("Error: cannot create URL")
                    return
                }
                // Create the url request
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "GET"
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("Error: error calling GET")
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Error: Did not receive data")
                        return
                    }
                    //print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
                    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 299) ~= response.statusCode else {
                        print("Error: HTTP request failed")
                        return
                    }
                    do {
                        guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
                            print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: []) else {
                            print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8)
                        else {
                            print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
                            return
                        }
                        //print(prettyPrintedJson)
                        jsonResponse = prettyPrintedJson
                    } catch {
                        print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                        return
                    }
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let jrData = jsonResponse.data(using: .utf8)
                    let jsonResponseProcessed = try! decoder.decode(ElevationResponse.self, from: jrData!)

            for i in 0..<listOfPointsToQuery.count{
                        processedElevation.append(jsonResponseProcessed.results[i].elevation)
                        print(processedElevation)
                        print("processed elevation data ^")
            }
            }
        task.resume()
        completeHandler(success)
    }
```

the closure is defined right after this function definition like so.

```
var completehandler:(Bool)->Void = { (sucess) in
        if sucess {
            print("Complete download data ")
                altitudeAdjustmentViaElevationData(elevationPointsList: processedElevation)
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
        
    }
```

finally the function is called like so.

```
ElevationRequest(listOfPointsToQuery: finalAutoPathPoints, success: true, completeHandler: completehandler)
```

a final note which seems worth mentioning. I am inexperienced so im not sure if this is of any relevance.

I am processing the json response within the same function as the call. The code is included in the first code segment above, the console response looks like this.

````
Complete download data 
[11.59268283843994]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359, 11.69645023345947]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359, 11.69645023345947, 11.79109859466553]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359, 11.69645023345947, 11.79109859466553, 11.35733222961426]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359, 11.69645023345947, 11.79109859466553, 11.35733222961426, 11.57364559173584]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359, 11.69645023345947, 11.79109859466553, 11.35733222961426, 11.57364559173584, 11.7429027557373]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359, 11.69645023345947, 11.79109859466553, 11.35733222961426, 11.57364559173584, 11.7429027557373, 12.02133083343506]
processed elevation data ^
[11.59268283843994, 11.68190288543701, 11.86490249633789, 11.53255939483643, 11.46291351318359, 11.69645023345947, 11.79109859466553, 11.35733222961426, 11.57364559173584, 11.7429027557373, 12.02133083343506, 11.66207313537598]
processed elevation data ^ ```
````

Comment: You have to call `completeHandler` **inside** the closure. Move the line up between the last two `}`. And instead of the unnecessary conversion with `JSONSerializtion` catch the error of `JSONDecoder`. A DecodingError is very descriptive.

Comment: @vadian hi thank you for the response. cancel that. I think its fixed now. thank you very much.

Comment: Please format your code. In Xcode press ⌘A and ⌃I. Replace `completeHandler:` with `completeHandler: @escaping`

Comment: thank you If you don't mind could you tell me why I might have this issue when using the closure to activate a function call. (Instance member 'altitudeAdjustmentViaElevationData' cannot be used on type 'MapViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?). (Instance member 'processedElevation' cannot be used on type 'MapViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?)

Comment: respond with an answer if you would like

Comment: There is no `altitudeAdjustmentViaElevationData` in the code

Comment: Sorry I altered the closure it looks- I included it in the code above I have just edited it

Comment: Apologies @vadian i didn't update the code snippet after making alterations it is there now and up to date.

Comment: It's a static, instance type issue. And it's still unclear because the declaration is missing. By the way you can delete `resultKeys` because they are completely useless.

Comment: thank you ill include the response apologies I thought it was an issue within the function call rather than the function itself. the code will be added above

Comment: Apologies @vadian I have now included the code for that function. respond with an answer so I can confirm your answer as solving my issue

Comment: Declare the completion handler as function. Replace the line `var completehandler:(Bool)->Void = { (sucess) in` with `func completehandler(_ sucess : Bool) {`

Comment: Thank you @vadian. Your answers have solved this for me, it is really appreciated apologies for not including all the necessary information from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit given to @vidian for their help answering this question.

Regarding the issue of execution prior to completion of the http requests response, this issue was rooted in my miss handling of the completion request.

The tail end of the first code segment is like so.

```
       }
            }
        task.resume()
        completeHandler(success)
    }
```

it should have been structured like this.

```
       }
       completeHandler(success)
            }
        task.resume()
    }
```

another issue within the code I had written was that the closure was not defined correctly. Defining it as a function solved the issue. Correct definition of the closure is below.

```
 func completehandler(_ sucess : Bool) {
        if sucess {
            print("Complete download data ")
               AltitudeAdjustmentViaElevationData(elevationPointsList: processedElevation)
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
        
    }
```